# Saving utf-8 encoded text with numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, utf-8

My input:

```
??AAAAT 66.5939
??AAAAW 63.3312
??AAAAZ 63.3312
??AAAĄB 58.0579
??AAAĄD 81.3312
??AAAĄF 87.3312
??AAAĄG 64.5562
??AAAĄH 63.3687
??AAAĄK 81.3312
??AAAĄL 81.3312
??AAAĄM 81.3312
??AAAĄN 79.3312
```

I have a script that takes the average of the second column, subtracts it from the original value and saves the modified columns to another file:

```
import numpy as np

def calculateAverage():
    '''real values of leaves should be averaged over all possible leaves'''

    values = np.loadtxt("input/leaves.txt", usecols=(1,))
    leaves = np.loadtxt("input/leaves.txt", dtype='str', usecols=(0,))

    values -= np.mean(values)
    outputFile = open("output/leaves.txt", 'w')

    for i, elem in enumerate(leaves):
        outputFile.write('%s %f\n' % (leaves[i], values[i]))

    outputFile.close()
```

Now, I am trying to do the same with a record array:

```
import numpy as np
def calculateAverage1():
    '''real values of leaves should be averaged over all possible leaves'''

    values = np.loadtxt("input/leaves.txt", dtype=[('key', 'S8'), ('val', 'f8')])

    values['val'] -= np.mean(values['val'])

    np.savetxt("output/leaves.txt", values, fmt='%s %f')
```

The output from the first script looks just like the input when I'm opening it with emacs or other editors. The output from the second script though defaults to utf-8 decoded characters:

```
??AAAAT -11.730239
??AAAAW -14.992939
??AAAAZ -14.992939
??AAA\304\204B -20.266239
??AAA\304\204D 3.007061
??AAA\304\204F 9.007061
??AAA\304\204G -13.767939
??AAA\304\204H -14.955439
??AAA\304\204K 3.007061
??AAA\304\204L 3.007061
??AAA\304\204M 3.007061
??AAA\304\204N 1.007061
```

I have to specifically choose utf-8 in an editor in order for them to show properly (i.e. encoded).

How to force numpy to save a file so that it's utf-8 encoded? Is this a problem with numpy or might it be OS-specific? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.6, numpy 1.8.1.

Comment: Facing the same on Ubuntu 16.10, python 3.5

Comment: I had similar problems on Ubuntu recently, and I dealt with problem characters by explicitly declaring ``encoding='utf8'`` in the ``savetext`` args.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't anything but a quick and dirty solution, but it worked for my (much much simpler) case. Rather than saving to utf-8 directly, you can save to a temporary file, and then do a second pass through to convert from whatever encoding numpy defaults to (in my Ubuntu 14.04, python 3.4.0, numpy 1.9.2 case iso-8859-1) to utf-8.

```
np.savetxt('foo', data, **kwargs)
with open('foo', 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as fin, open('bar', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write(line)
```

You can figure out what formatting numpy is writing by running

```
 $ file -i foo
```

at the command line.